# could not open base file "base/13322/1259":Permission denied

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-9.6

While i am log in to my PostgreSQL database, I am getting following error:

```
ERROR: could not open file "base/13322/1259": Permission Denied
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either somebody messed up the permissions of your database files and directories (they must belong to the PostgreSQL operating system user), or some anti-virus software is messing with the database files (then the error should be transient).